# BI Publisher > Avoiding Table to split into next page

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have a BIP rtf template that has a table with bunch of fields. The report consists of multiple records and not just a single record. Now requirement is that if the table of next records fits in the same page then place it on the same page else print it on the next page.

For example: it should **not** be like this:

[image]

Instead No. 1-236586771 should have been started on page 2.

Here is what i tried to fix this issue but no luck so far:

1. Unchecked "Allow row to break across pages"
   [image]
2. In the paragraph, selected "Keep with next" and "Keep lines together"
   [image: List item]

Please these are my sample xml and rtf:
[xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub58sbel8ssxgfr/BIP%20ROH%20SR%20Generic%20Report.xml?dl=0), [rtf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52mh0zqgyd18ztj/stack.rtf?dl=0)

Please i need help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to nest the tables.

Put the for-each ssServiceRequest in the first table. Set that row to not break across pages.  You'd probably want three columns (1: begin for each, 2: content, 3: end for each).

Put a new content table inside the first table row that is repeating. But all your display elements inside that table.

Comment: This should work. Invisible, nested tables is the only way to get formatting correct in BIP.

Comment: Good point Ranjith; the outer table can be invisible (no defined borders). It may helpful for you to "view gridlines" in the Word table layout ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

What may also help is-

- Highlight the **whole table**, right click and select table
  properties.
- Click on the row tab and tick the "Repeat as header row    at the top
  of the page" box. (untick allow row to break across pages    if it is
  ticked).

What will occur is rather than a row splitting to the next page the whole table will appear in the next page. This will only occur if a table's row breaks to the next page.
Hope this helps or gives another option for future use.

Comment: This trick does not work. I played with this earlier but this never have worked for me. I needed to place page-break on the correct spot to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is sometimes it does not work, have not figured out why. Good solution will also take that on board. Thanks